# ReactJS - Passing selected variable from list to render

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently learning ReactJS and i would like to select one of few listed items and display it in Flex tag (from Patternfly).

```
const locals = ['Camera', 'Car', 'Monitor'];
function showItem(loc) {
  console.log(loc)
  return(loc);
}

const listLocals = locals.map((locals) =>
    <text stroke="black" onClick={() => (showItem(locals))}>{locals}</text>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Grid hasGutter>
    <GridItem span={4} rowSpan={2}>
    {listLocals}
    </GridItem>
    <GridItem span={2} rowSpan={3}>

  <Card isHoverable isFullHeight>
    <CardTitle>Information Panel</CardTitle>
    <CardBody>
        <Flex>
            <FlexItem>Selected:</FlexItem>
            <FlexItem>{showItem}</FlexItem>
        </Flex>
    </CardBody>
  </Card>
    </GridItem>
  </Grid>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I've tried but after few hours i'm done and i'm just frustrated ;D
In: `console.log(loc)` i see what i've selected but can't passing it through, and i know that i'm pobably doing something really dumb but, please show me where :D

Thanks for any help, or tips.

Comment: in what way would it be "selected"? where is the state stored? on the parent component?

Answer (score 0):

Tip: You can use the state variable to display the selected local.
Step1: initialize the state variable as
const [showItem,updateShowItem]=useState(null)
Step2: in on click method call the updateShoeItem function with selected value as
updateShowItem(loc)
Step3: use showItem variable in ur jsx

Here when ever ur state changes the react component will rerender with latest value.

Answer (score 0):

Move code from index to App component =)

You need:

1. Add state [about state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). [about hook useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState('')
```

2. Add event onClick

```
        {locals.map((local, idx) => 
          <text key={idx} onClick={() => setSelected(local)}>{local}</text>
        )}
```

3. Add the output of the selected item

```
<span>Selected: {selected}</span>
```

[CodeSanbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-violet-udyw5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you for your time and that example ;)